# Arduino - C++ Object Constructor Error

Tags: c++, arduino

I am attempting to debug some of my arduino code and keep getting errors associated with object constructors. I believe I have everything correctly defined and feeding the correct inputs, but I still can't get the code to compile.

I pasted the error and code below. Note that I have removed some of my source code in the 'Data Control' class. Also note that CDOS_Info is a struct that I have created.

Thanks for any help!

Error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.5 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Uno"

C:\Users\A5KW5ZZ\Desktop\arduino-1.6.5-r2-windows\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\CDOS\StateController.cpp: In constructor 'StateController::StateController(CDOS_Info*)':
C:\Users\A5KW5ZZ\Desktop\arduino-1.6.5-r2-windows\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\CDOS\StateController.cpp:19:58: error: no matching function for call to 'DataControl::DataControl()'
  StateController::StateController(CDOS_Info *inputtedInfo)
                                                          ^
C:\Users\A5KW5ZZ\Desktop\arduino-1.6.5-r2-windows\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\CDOS\StateController.cpp:19:58: note: candidates are:
In file included from C:\Users\A5KW5ZZ\Desktop\arduino-1.6.5-r2-windows\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\CDOS\StateController.h:16:0,
                 from C:\Users\A5KW5ZZ\Desktop\arduino-1.6.5-r2-windows\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\CDOS\StateController.cpp:13:
C:\Users\A5KW5ZZ\Desktop\arduino-1.6.5-r2-windows\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\CDOS\DataControl.h:19:3: note: DataControl::DataControl(CDOS_Info*)
   DataControl(CDOS_Info *inputtedInfo);
   ^
C:\Users\A5KW5ZZ\Desktop\arduino-1.6.5-r2-windows\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\CDOS\DataControl.h:19:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
C:\Users\A5KW5ZZ\Desktop\arduino-1.6.5-r2-windows\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\CDOS\DataControl.h:16:7: note: DataControl::DataControl(const DataControl&)
 class DataControl
       ^
C:\Users\A5KW5ZZ\Desktop\arduino-1.6.5-r2-windows\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\CDOS\DataControl.h:16:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Error compiling.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

Code

Main:

```
/***********************************************
 *********** Import Libraries ******************
 ***********************************************/

  #include "CDOS_Definitions.h"  
  #include "ConfigInit.h"
  #include "SensorSerialInterface.h"
  #include "StateController.h"
  #include "OutputInterface.h"
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>   

/***********************************************
 ******* Declare datatypes/objects *************
 ***********************************************/

  CDOS_Info info;                                       // Datatype holds general information regarding the CDOS
  CDOS_Info * infoPointer = &info;                      // Declare and define a pointer of the CDOS_Info datatype
  ConfigInit configInit(infoPointer);                   // Configures & initializes the CDOS
  SensorSerialInterface sensorInterface(infoPointer);   // Controls the communications between the Arduino and IMU    
  StateController stateController(infoPointer);         // Transitions the CDOS between various states
  OutputInterface outputMessage(infoPointer);           // Outputted serial message providing status information to a computer terminal

/***********************************************
 *************** Main Program  *****************
 ***********************************************/

void setup(){
  configInit.config();
  configInit.init();
  sensorInterface.setAllOutput(); // Force IMU to output status of accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer
}

void loop(){
  sensorInterface.readAll(info.accelXYZ, info.gyroXYZ, info.magXYZ);  // Get sensor data
  stateController.routine();                                          // Jump into state transition logic
  outputMessage.outputSerial();                                       // Output CDOS status info

}
```

State Controller Header:

```
#ifndef StateController_h
#define StateController_h

#include "CDOS_Definitions.h"
#include "InputInterface.h"
#include "DataControl.h"
#include "LEDController.h"

class StateController
{
    public:
        StateController(CDOS_Info *inputtedInfo);
        void routine(void);

    private:
        CDOS_Info *info;                // create copy of CDOS_Info pointer that member functions can access and modify
        InputInterface userInput;       // Create input interface object
        DataControl dataControl;        // Create data control object
        LEDController lightController;  // Controls the LEDs on the CDOS
};

#endif
```

State Controller Source Code:

```
 #include "Arduino.h"
 #include "CDOS_Definitions.h"
 #include "StateController.h"
 #include "LEDController.h"
 #include "InputInterface.h"
 #include "DataControl.h"


 StateController::StateController(CDOS_Info *inputtedInfo)
 { 
    info = inputtedInfo;
    userInput = InputInterface();
    dataControl = DataControl(info);
    lightController = LEDController();
 }

 void StateController::routine(void)
 {
     int static previousTime;
     int currentTime = millis();
     bool static startTime = false;
     int teachTime = 5000; 

     // State 0 - Start Up State
     if(info->currentState == 0)
     {
         // Transition Case
         if(userInput.getDigitalInput())
         {
             info->currentState = 3;
             previousTime = currentTime;
         }

         // Lighting
         lightController.setLightConfig0();
     }

     // State 1 - Disturbed State
     else if(info->currentState == 1)
     {
        // Transition Case
        if(userInput.getDigitalInput())
        {
            info->currentState = 3;
            previousTime = currentTime;
        }

        // Compute vertical angle
        dataControl.calculateVerticalAngle();

        // Lighting
        lightController.setLightConfig1();
     }

     // State 2 - Faulted State
     else if(info->currentState == 2)
     {
         // Haven't created any cases where the system can fault yet, will finish later

         // Lighting
         lightController.setLightConfig2();
     }

     // State 3 - Teaching State
     else if(info->currentState == 3)
     {

         // Transition Case
         if(abs(currentTime - previousTime) > teachTime)
         {
             info->currentState = 4;
             dataControl.teachNewPosition();
         }

         // Lighting
         lightController.setLightConfig3();
     }   

     // State 4 - Taught State
     else if(info->currentState == 4)
     {
         // Transition Case
         if(dataControl.checkPosition())
         {
             info->currentState = 1;
         }

         // Compute vertical angle
         dataControl.calculateVerticalAngle();

         // Lighting
         lightController.setLightConfig4();
     }       
 }
```

Data Control Header:

```
#ifndef DataControl_h
#define DataControl_h

#include "CDOS_Definitions.h"

class DataControl
{
    public:
        DataControl(CDOS_Info *inputtedInfo);
        void teachNewPosition(void);
        bool checkPosition(void);
        void calculateVerticalAngle(void);      

    private:
        CDOS_Info *info;    // create copy of CDOS_Info pointer that member functions can access and modify
};

#endif
```

Data Control Source Code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "DataControl.h"
#include "CDOS_Definitions.h"
#include "SensorSerialInterface.h"


DataControl::DataControl(CDOS_Info *inputtedInfo)
{   
    info = inputtedInfo;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an object without calling its constructor. Because a `StateController` is also a `DataControl`, you can't create one without calling `DataControl`'s constructor (as well as `StateController`'s). But that constructor takes an argument, so the compiler can't add the call for you.

The way to call a base class's constructor is to modify the derived class's constructor like so:

```
StateController::StateController(CDOS_Info *inputtedInfo)
    : DataControl(inputtedInfo) // calls DataControl's constructor
{
   // info = inputtedInfo; // Don't need this, because DataControl's constructor does it.
   userInput = InputInterface();
   dataControl = DataControl(info);
   lightController = LEDController();
}
```

Pay attention to the weird syntax - this is not exactly a normal function call. And yes, it *does* go outside the curly brackets.

Comment: Hmmm... That's interesting. I'm new to C++, is what I'm doing frowned upon? Or is what I've done pretty common? I'm always looking for best practices techniques. Thanks for the response! I'll follow up with whether or not this fixes my issue!